# CreateProcess vs. CreateFile EXE

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, createprocess

[Edited]

- `CreateProcess` creates a process (for example, from `.exe` file)
- `CreateFile` can create / open a file. If it opens an `.exe` file, that execution file will run. In this case, is it equal to CreateProcess?

Are there any differences in this case? I'm new to this, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your description of what these functions do is incorrect.  They serve completely separate purposes.

- `CreateProcess` will *run* an executable file as a process.  It will not create a file.

  > Creates a new process and its primary thread. The new process runs in the security context of the calling process.

  Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)
- `CreateFile` will open or create a file.  It will *not* execute that file as a process.

  > Creates or opens a file or I/O device. The most commonly used I/O devices are as follows: file, file stream, directory, physical disk, volume, console buffer, tape drive, communications resource, mailslot, and pipe. The function returns a handle that can be used to access the file or device for various types of I/O depending on the file or device and the flags and attributes specified.

  Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask, what is the result of `CreateFile` when it opens a .exe file? Will the .exe file run?

Comment: @Huyen the result of (successfully) opening a file using `CreateFile()` is a handle to the opened file which you can then use, e.g., to read the contents of the file. Whether the filename contains an extension and what that extension may be is completely irrelevant…

Comment: @huyen no, I thought I made that clear.  There is nothing special about a .exe file -- it's just data.  The only additional meaning is that a .exe extension is recognized by parts of the operating system as one of a few kinds of file that are intended to be executable.  It would be absolutely untenable for a file to execute just because you wanted to read or write its bytes.